# My TextChanged event on a dynamically created textbox in a custom BoundField never fires?

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, boundfield

I'm trying to make a custom `BoundField` (Column) for my custom `GridView`.  I added textboxes to the `FooterRow` to manage filtering on columns.  It displays well, but the `TextChanged` event is never raised.  I guess it is because the textboxes are recreated on each postback, and not persisted.

Here is my code:

```
public class Column : BoundField
{
    public override void InitializeCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlCellType cellType, DataControlRowState rowState, int rowIndex)
    {
        base.InitializeCell(cell, cellType, rowState, rowIndex);
        if (cellType == DataControlCellType.Footer)
        {
            TextBox txtFilter = new TextBox();
            txtFilter.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            txtFilter.Text = "";
            txtFilter.AutoPostBack = true;
            txtFilter.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtFilter_TextChanged);
            cell.Controls.Add(txtFilter);
        }
    }

    protected void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Never get here
    }
}
```

I tried with a checkbox, and it worked.

Comment: is it winforms or asp.net?

Comment: you can post your own answer - and mark it as accepted

Comment: you must not change Id property of any control,so that it was not working. It should not be changed in coding

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in a WPF app. It was simply work for me like this way,

```
 TextBox txtBx = new TextBox();
 txtBx.Width = 300;
 txtBx.TextChanged += txtBox_TextChanged;
```

And It calls,

```
private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        errorTxt.Text = "Its working";
    }
```

"errorTxt" is a pre defined TextBlock. Hope this will help some one..

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I finally found the problem, but I don't understand it !
The problem was the ID property, generated with a Guid. Just removing it solved my problem.

```
public class Column : BoundField
{
    public override void InitializeCell(DataControlFieldCell cell, DataControlCellType cellType, DataControlRowState rowState, int rowIndex)
    {
        base.InitializeCell(cell, cellType, rowState, rowIndex);
        if (cellType == DataControlCellType.Footer)
        {
            TextBox txtFilter = new TextBox();
            // Removing this worked
            //txtFilter.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
            txtFilter.Text = "";
            txtFilter.AutoPostBack = true;
            txtFilter.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtFilter_TextChanged);
            cell.Controls.Add(txtFilter);
        }
    }

    protected void txtFilter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Never get here
    }
}
```